# How avoid interval with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape Craiglist with Mechanize. I code this:

```
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get("http://paris.craigslist.fr/search/apa")
i = 0
list_per_page = 99
while i <= list_per_page do
    title = page.search(".hdrlnk")[i].text
    price = page.search(".price")[i].text
    puts title
    puts price
    puts "-----------"
    i+=1
end
```

It works but when a listing hasn't any price there is an interval. I think it's because I use `search()[i]` but I don't know what I have to do to avoid interval. Any idea?

Edit:
On Craiglist there is:

```
listing_title1 -> $100
listing_title2 -> $200
listing_title3 -> 
listing_title4 -> $60
listing_title5 -> $150
```

My output CSV displays:

```
listing_title1 -> $100
listing_title2 -> $200
listing_title3 -> $60
listing_title4 -> $150
listing_title5 -> $300
```

$300 is listing_title6

Comment: Can you post what the output is at the moment and what you would like it to be? It's not very clear what you mean by 'interval'.

Comment: I edit my post with more explain

Comment: try the code in my edited answer, it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'interval' you mean the blank line that is printed when the listing doesn't have a price, you could fix this by making the `puts` conditional:

`puts price unless price.empty?`

### Edit

If I understand right, your `hdrlnk` and `price` entries are getting out of sync with each other. This happens because your current loop is skipping entries with blank `price` fields and going straight to the next one.

The best way to get around this is to find a container that includes both `price` and `hdrlnk` and iterate over those instead of over the `hdrlnk` and `price` entries separately.  On this page that would be the `.row` which contains all the info for each search result. So something like this would work:

```
page.search(".row").each do |row|
  title = row.search(".hdrlnk").first
  price = row.search(".price").first
  puts title.text if title
  puts price.text if price
  puts "------------"
end
```

Comment: When the listing doesn't have a price there is no blank, it displays the next price instead of a blank. `unless price.empty?` doesn't work.

Comment: @Rubyx I think I get it now, I made an edit to my answer. It works for me like this.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already accepted an answer and that's fine, but I wanted to introduce the concept of `next` which is a more powerful solution than putting `if <thing>` checks all over.

Your method could look like this:

```
while <condition> do
  title = page.search(".hdrlnk")[i].text
  price = page.search(".price")[i].text

  # skip to the next iteration if any of the vars are nil
  next unless [title, price].all?

  # ... the rest of code
end
```

By the way, I think you're usage of the term 'interval' is a bit misleading. I think of an interval as a special kind of loop which runs on a specified *time* interval, i.e. every second or minute. It's probably clearer to use the terms `loop` or `iteration` in this case.

Comment: While `next` is a useful tool, and you're right that the looping could benefit from further optimization, this wouldn't actually work. The problem was that `page.search` returns an array of all matching entries on the page, but since some entries had a missing `.price` element (which `page.search` just ignored) the two arrays had different numbers of entries - so accessing the two arrays via `[i]` would not necessarily show the title and price of the same apartment.